# How to get objectId, bucketId, etc from Google Pub/Sub

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using a Pub/Sub topic which triggers when an object is created in a GCS bucket. Here's the code I've got at the moment:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def index():

    envelope = request.get_json()
    myfunc(envelope)

    return "", 204


def myfunc(envelope):
    event_type = envelope.get("eventType")
    bucket_id = envelope.get("bucketId")
    object_id = envelope.get("objectId")
    
    print(event_type)
    print(bucket_id)
    print(object_id)
```

At the moment this just prints out `'None'` for each print. I want it to print the values associated with the `objectId`, `bucketId`, `etc keys`, so that I'm able to get the filename of the file that appeared in the GCS bucket.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is `envelope` supposed to be the message? If so, this github example should help you on parsing the message properly. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/notification_polling.py

Comment: The example above shows the Event type,Bucket ID,Object ID and Generation whenever an object is created on the bucket that is connected to the pub/sub topic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure.... But I guess that the signature of your function is not correct...

[Google Cloud Storage Triggers - object finalize example](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize)

Comment: Yeah it is definitely wrong in some way. But that link is for a trigger when object gets finalized, not a pubsub trigger. I need the latter because I need to be able to nack/ack the messages.

Comment: If you have a "push" pubsub subscription (the cloud function is triggered by the message), from the best of my knowledge, you won't be able to acknowledge the message from inside your code...

Answer (score 0):

When you use a push subscription, you receive the PubSub message in a POST body in JSON format. The schema of the message is compliant to the [API spec documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage)